# Django dynamic url arguements missing

Tags: django

Can someone spot the mistake? What i'm expecting to happen is to dynamically pass in the ids of the classes I have created, so that I can update an entry I created in a previous form.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_type_4_service' type_4_service.order_reference.id type_4_service.id %}>Update</a></td>
```

Here is my urls:

```
path('order/<str:pk_test>/update_type_4_service/<str:pk>', views.updateType_4_Service, name="update_type_4_service"),
```

Here is my views:

```
def updateType_4_Service(request, pk_test, pk):
    type_4_service = Type_4_Service.objects.get(id=pk)
    type_4_service_form = Type_4_ServiceForm(instance=type_4_service)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        type_4_service_form = Type_4_ServiceForm(request.POST, order_reference=order)
        type_4_service_form.instance.order_reference = order
        if type_4_service_form.is_valid():
            type_4_service_form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'type_4_service_form': type_4_service_form}
    return render(request, 'orchestration/type_4_service_form.html', context)
```

This is the error:

```
Reverse for 'update_type_4_service' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['order/(?P<pk_test>[^/]+)/update_type_4_service/(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

Comment: Okay, so type_4_service.order_reference.id type_4_service.id should have been each_type_4_service.order_reference.id each_type_4_service.id

Comment: There was a missing " in my HTML

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the name too:

```
<td>
    <a 
        class="btn btn-sm btn-info" 
        href="{% url 'update_type_4_service' pk_test=type_4_service.order_reference.id pk=type_4_service.id %}"
    >
        Update
    </a>
</td>
```